# C++17 variant<any> inside the class

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, variant

The following code compiles well:

```
int main()
{
    variant<any> var;
    var = 5;
    cout << any_cast<int>(get<any>(var)) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But when I'm trying to put `variant<any>` as a class member

```
struct MyClass{
    variant<any> var;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass s;
    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't compile. Am I doing something wrong or it is some bug?

I'm using gcc 7.1.0

```
In file included from /home/zak/Projects/Anytest/main.cpp:3:0:
/usr/local/gcc-7.1/include/c++/7.1.0/variant: In instantiation of ‘struct std::__detail::__variant::__accepted_index<const std::variant<std::any>&, std::variant<std::any>, void>’:
/usr/local/gcc-7.1/include/c++/7.1.0/variant:911:26:   required from ‘constexpr const size_t std::variant<std::any>::__accepted_index<const std::variant<std::any>&>’
/usr/local/gcc-7.1/include/c++/7.1.0/variant:940:6:   required by substitution of ‘template<class _Tp, class> constexpr std::variant<std::any>::variant(_Tp&&) [with _Tp = const std::variant<std::any>&; <template-parameter-1-2> = <missing>]’
/home/zak/Projects/Anytest/main.cpp:14:13:   required from here
/usr/local/gcc-7.1/include/c++/7.1.0/variant:559:49: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::__detail::__variant::__overload_set<std::any>::_S_fun(const std::variant<std::any>&)’
       decltype(__overload_set<_Types...>::_S_fun(std::declval<_Tp>()),
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/gcc-7.1/include/c++/7.1.0/variant:541:58: note: candidate: static std::integral_constant<long unsigned int, sizeof... (_Rest)> std::__detail::__variant::__overload_set<_First, _Rest ...>::_S_fun(_First) [with _First = std::any; _Rest = {}]
       static integral_constant<size_t, sizeof...(_Rest)> _S_fun(_First);
                                                          ^~~~~~
/usr/local/gcc-7.1/include/c++/7.1.0/variant:541:58: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const std::variant<std::any>’ to ‘std::any’
/usr/local/gcc-7.1/include/c++/7.1.0/variant:535:19: note: candidate: static void std::__detail::__variant::__overload_set<_Types>::_S_fun() [with _Types = {}]
     { static void _S_fun(); };
                   ^~~~~~
/usr/local/gcc-7.1/include/c++/7.1.0/variant:535:19: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/local/gcc-7.1/include/c++/7.1.0/variant:559:49: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::__detail::__variant::__overload_set<std::any>::_S_fun(const std::variant<std::any>&)’
       decltype(__overload_set<_Types...>::_S_fun(std::declval<_Tp>()),
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/gcc-7.1/include/c++/7.1.0/variant:541:58: note: candidate: static std::integral_constant<long unsigned int, sizeof... (_Rest)> std::__detail::__variant::__overload_set<_First, _Rest ...>::_S_fun(_First) [with _First = std::any; _Rest = {}]
       static integral_constant<size_t, sizeof...(_Rest)> _S_fun(_First);
                                                          ^~~~~~
/usr/local/gcc-7.1/include/c++/7.1.0/variant:541:58: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const std::variant<std::any>’ to ‘std::any’
/usr/local/gcc-7.1/include/c++/7.1.0/variant:535:19: note: candidate: static void std::__detail::__variant::__overload_set<_Types>::_S_fun() [with _Types = {}]
     { static void _S_fun(); };
                   ^~~~~~
/usr/local/gcc-7.1/include/c++/7.1.0/variant:535:19: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/local/gcc-7.1/include/c++/7.1.0/variant:559:49: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::__detail::__variant::__overload_set<std::any>::_S_fun(const std::variant<std::any>&)’
       decltype(__overload_set<_Types...>::_S_fun(std::declval<_Tp>()),
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/gcc-7.1/include/c++/7.1.0/variant:541:58: note: candidate: static std::integral_constant<long unsigned int, sizeof... (_Rest)> std::__detail::__variant::__overload_set<_First, _Rest ...>::_S_fun(_First) [with _First = std::any; _Rest = {}]
       static integral_constant<size_t, sizeof...(_Rest)> _S_fun(_First);
                                                          ^~~~~~
/usr/local/gcc-7.1/include/c++/7.1.0/variant:541:58: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const std::variant<std::any>’ to ‘std::any’
/usr/local/gcc-7.1/include/c++/7.1.0/variant:535:19: note: candidate: static void std::__detail::__variant::__overload_set<_Types>::_S_fun() [with _Types = {}]
     { static void _S_fun(); };
                   ^~~~~~
/usr/local/gcc-7.1/include/c++/7.1.0/variant:535:19: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/local/gcc-7.1/include/c++/7.1.0/variant: In instantiation of ‘constexpr const size_t std::__detail::__variant::__accepted_index<const std::variant<std::any>&, std::variant<std::any>, void>::value’:
/usr/local/gcc-7.1/include/c++/7.1.0/variant:911:26:   required from ‘constexpr const size_t std::variant<std::any>::__accepted_index<const std::variant<std::any>&>’
/usr/local/gcc-7.1/include/c++/7.1.0/variant:940:6:   required by substitution of ‘template<class _Tp, class> constexpr std::variant<std::any>::variant(_Tp&&) [with _Tp = const std::variant<std::any>&; <template-parameter-1-2> = <missing>]’
/home/zak/Projects/Anytest/main.cpp:14:13:   required from here
/usr/local/gcc-7.1/include/c++/7.1.0/variant:564:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::__detail::__variant::__overload_set<std::any>::_S_fun(const std::variant<std::any>&)’
  - decltype(__overload_set<_Types...>::
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      _S_fun(std::declval<_Tp>()))::value;
      ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/gcc-7.1/include/c++/7.1.0/variant:541:58: note: candidate: static std::integral_constant<long unsigned int, sizeof... (_Rest)> std::__detail::__variant::__overload_set<_First, _Rest ...>::_S_fun(_First) [with _First = std::any; _Rest = {}]
       static integral_constant<size_t, sizeof...(_Rest)> _S_fun(_First);
                                                          ^~~~~~
/usr/local/gcc-7.1/include/c++/7.1.0/variant:541:58: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const std::variant<std::any>’ to ‘std::any’
/usr/local/gcc-7.1/include/c++/7.1.0/variant:535:19: note: candidate: static void std::__detail::__variant::__overload_set<_Types>::_S_fun() [with _Types = {}]
     { static void _S_fun(); };
                   ^~~~~~
/usr/local/gcc-7.1/include/c++/7.1.0/variant:535:19: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, replacing the default initialization with value initialization, makes the code compile fine on GCC. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d45087050b803e45

Comment: Deleting the copy constructor also makes the code compile: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7481101122a17a0

Comment: Compiling the second example with Visual Studio 2017 and the `/std:c++latest` flag works perfectly. Either GCC goofed up, or MSVC lucked out. I will test further...

Comment: clang compiles it too, but still using Microsoft's C++ implementation. Must be something off in GCC's implementation

Comment: I've posted a [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80737)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is with `MyClass`'s implicitly defined copy constructor, when it tries to copy construct the member of type `std::variant<std::any>`.

To perform overload resolution, the compiler first needs to try to instantiate all of `std::variant`'s constructor templates, with the function argument being a `const std::variant<std::any>&`<sup>1</sup>. The constructor of our interest is this one:

```
template <class T> constexpr variant(T&& t) noexcept(/*...*/);
```

It only participates in overload resolution if, among others, the expression `FUN(​std​::​forward<T>(t))` is well formed, where `FUN` is a set of overloaded functions produced according to [[variant.ctor]/12](http://eel.is/c++draft/variant.ctor#12).<sup>2</sup>

In this case, there is only one alternative type (`std::any`), so there is only one imaginary function `FUN`, whose signature is `FUN(std::any)`. Now, the compiler needs to decide whether `FUN` can be called with a `const std::variant<std::any>&`<sup>1</sup>. In this process, the compiler needs to know whether `std::any` can be constructed with `const std::variant<std::any>&`<sup>1</sup>.

This will trigger the instantiation of `std::any`'s constructor template `template<class T> any(T&& value);`, which only participates in overload resolution if `std::is_­copy_­constructible_­v<VT>` is `true` (`VT` being `std::decay_t<T>`, and `T` being `const std::variant<std::any>&`).

Now in order to see whether `VT` (i.e. `std::variant<std::any>`) is copy constructible, the compiler needs to try to instantiate all of `std::variant`'s constructor templates... and this is where we started, and we are stuck in a loop.

This can explain why we see `template<class _Tp, class> constexpr std::variant<std::any>::variant(_Tp&&)` and `__overload_set<std::any>::_S_fun` (which corresponds to the function `FUN` mentioned above) in the error message, and why we see the same error appearing several times.

It remains a question how GCC breaks from the above loop, and why tweaking the program can stop GCC from reporting the error. Maybe these are indication of some bug.

---

<sup>1. Strictly speaking, it should be "an lvalue of type `const std::variant<std::any>`" rather than "a `const std::variant<std::any>&`".</sup>

<sup>2. The standard also requires that this constructor shall only participate in overload resolution if `is_­same_­v<decay_­t<T>, variant>` is `false`. GCC (libstdc++) chooses to check that later. I don't know whether this is conforming.</sup>